# Is $F[x]/(x^2)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Where $F[x]$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients in the field $F$; $(x^2)$ is an ideal.

My thought is yes. But, I feel something must go wrong because $x^2$ isn't irreducible.

Let $[f(x)]=F(x)+(x^2)$

By the Division algorithm we know any element of the quotient ring is of the form: $[P(x)]=a+bx+(x^2)$

So for $[q(x)]$ to be a multiplicative inverse,
$[P(x)][Q(x)]=(a+bx)(c+dx)+k(x)x^2=1+k(x)x^2$

So $ac=1$ and $cb+ad=0$ which is possible under suitable constraints on $c$ and $d$

What do you think?

Comment: As a more hands on approach, with your own argument, if $aX+b$ is multiplicative inverse of $X$, then since $X^2 = 0$, we have $bX=1$, or $X=b^{-1}$! The indeterminant became a number!!! So $X$ has no inverse.

Comment: It's the "division algorithm," not "diversion algorithm."

Answer (score 1):

No, because the image of $x$ in $\frac{k[x]}{x^2}$ is a divisor of zero

Comment: To put this in the language of the OP, the constraint $ac=1$ can't actually be solved if $a=0$ regardless of what $c$ is.

Answer (score 1):

No, since $x$ is nilpotent in that ring. A field has no zero-divisors, let alone nilpotent elements. Since $F[x]$ is a PID, $F[x]/(p(x)$is a field if and only if $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial.